# How can I read specific data from given html document in Data Table in c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

Here is my html document of belarc advisor, I want to read some specific data from it like Operating System, Drives, Memory in Data Table. 
[image]

> Note: I have done such task like read excel files in data grid view. But I am not aware about how can I read specific data from html document.

So is it possible to read only specific data from html document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at: https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Also the default `XmlDocument` class should be able to parse the HTML.

Or regular expressions are an option: http://mahmoud-alam.blogspot.com/2008/02/some-times-we-need-to-extract.html

What that means is you have to load the page and then look for the datatable you would like to extract.